# Css Gradient Border colors

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to add gradient colors to the borders of my webpage as well as a box shadow, it is currently working fine in Firefox but will not work in Chrome or I.E.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in Advanced.

Here is My Css:

```
#bodywrapper {
width:1000px;
background-color:#b69d85;
float:left;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #111111;
border-left: 8px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-left-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
    -moz-border-left-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
border-top: 8px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-top-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
    -moz-border-top-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-bottom-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
border-right: 8px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-right-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
    -moz-border-right-colors: #665546 #73604f #84705d #84705d #97826d #97826d #aa927c #b69d85;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit broswers do not support linear gradients (radial neither as far as I know) for borders. However, there are ways to achieve something very similar and more dependable across all browsers.

**BOX-SHADOW**

```
.box{
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

If you work the depth correctly you will get the effect of it as the fade of the shadow gives the impression of a gradient.

**BORDER INSET/OUTSET**

```
.box{
    border: 2px inset #888888;
}
```

This gives you a similar effect to the radial gradient. Yes, it is a far similarity, but it beats not having a cross-browser UI.

EDIT -

Here is a version of what I saw from your code in Firefox, now working in all browsers. Open in Firefox to see the similarity, open in Chrome to see it working there as well.

In order to add the back shadow, you may need to nest two divs to apply a border-shadow to each. All three examples are demonstrated in my demo

[***CODEPEN***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegbGd)

Comment: *Webkit broswers do not support linear gradients ... for borders* - I don't know what you meant to say but WebKit browsers do support gradients for borders when used along with `border-image`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the property `-moz-border-xxxx-colors` is only supported by Firefox adding webkit/non-FF prefixing will not make it be supported by other browsers

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-border-left-colors)

> ***This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.***
>
> In Mozilla applications like Firefox, the -moz-border-left-colors CSS property sets a list of colors for the left border.
>
> **This property is not part of any specification.**